# Оформление заголовка главного окна приложения для OS X

Tags: gui, macos, ui

Пишу программу, которая, в том числе, будет собираться и для OS X. Для Windows/X11 мой заголовок окна будет выглядеть подобным образом:

```
Название моей программы :: версия 1.2 (сборка 2345) x64
```

**Вопросы:**

- какую информацию в заголовок главного окна принято выводить в программах, работающих под управлением OS X?
- какой документ это регулирует/рекомендует?

Comment: Не забудьте открывать меню настроек по `Cmd+,` )

Comment: Спасибо! Я нашел себе увлекательное чтиво (см.ниже), наверное там и про это есть)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Нашел самостоятельно**

Документ, который рекомендует построение GUI для OS X называется [macOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/WindowNaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH35-SW1). В разделе "Naming Windows" жестких требований нет. Но дальнейшая ссылка на "The App Menu" требования уточняет. А именно:

> **If possible, use one word for the app menu title.** Using a short name helps make room for the rest of your app’s menus. If your app’s name is too long, provide a short name that’s about 16 characters or fewer. If you don’t provide a short name, the system might truncate the name from the end and add an ellipsis when the name is displayed in the menu bar.
>
> **Don’t include the app version number in the name.** Version information belongs in the About window.
>
> **Use the short app name in menu items that display it.** If you supplied a short app name, use it in the About, Hide, and Quit menu items.

Таким образом, для OS X оформление заголовка главного окна приложения нужно использовать только название программы (и желательно менее 16 символов).

Вопрос закрыт.